# Mac book pro 10.13.6 clean install on a year or two old machine

Tags: mac, hard-drive, macos, remote-control

I want to remove the "remote disk" not just from the side bar. I found on this site that from the terminal

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool false
killall Finder
```

This worked on older build. But with the new install /com.apple.NetworkBrowser is no longer in the /Library/Preferences directory.

I will never need or want to use "remote disk" can someone tell me how to get rid of it? Thank you.

Comment: The subject is about a macOS reinstall, the text about a Finder sidebar entry you want to remove. Can you please edit your question to make it more obvious what your question is, and also add a screenshot of the sidebar with the entry you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd be wary of removing it. I know that "no one uses CDs/DVDs any more" but every once in a while, someone breaks one out, like at a conference or a gift shop, etc.

So, Remote Disc allows you - using a laptop with no internal optical drive - to use a nearby computer (Windows or Mac) that *does* have an optical drive as your optical drive. Very practical. (You have to install CD or DVD Sharing for Windows 1.0)

But, if you really want to remove it from the sidebar, it's quite simple. Very Mac-like.

[image: Remove Remote disk from sidebar]

Just right-click the Remote disc and select "remove from sidebar."